# Using journal name as label when citing newspaper article without author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am wiring a thesis using biblatex and need to adjust the bibliography and citation style. I am using the [arthistory-bonn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-arthistory-bonn) bibliography style, but the same problem also applies to the standard styles, e.g. `authoryear`. I have made a custom copy of the arthistory-bonn style and added some small modifications, so adding further modifications would not be an issue.

I need to quote newspaper articles, some of which have an author, and some don't. I am using the `article` entry type. It currenty looks like this:

```tex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,italian,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Diss.bib}
@article{News1,
    journal   = {{Springfield Shopper}},
    title    = {The revolutionary monorail},
    year     = {2020},
    date     = {2020-12-23},
    url      =  {http://example.com},
    urldate  = {2021-12-12}
}

@article{News2,
    journal   = {{Springfield Shopper}},
    title    = {About tire fires},
    year     = {2020},
    date     = {2020-12-23},
    url      =  {http://example.com},
    urldate  = {2021-12-12},
    author  = {Kent Brookman}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=arthistory-bonn,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,language=auto,backref=false,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Diss.bib}

\begin{document}

It's science if you quote things\autocite{News1,News2}.


\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

In the first entry, I need to change the date to only the year inside the label, i.e. "Brookman 2020" instead of "Brookman (23. Dezember 2020)".

In the second entry, I need the label to contain the journal name, i.e. "Springfield Shopper 2020", i.e. the journal name should replace the author. Currently, biblatex puts the article title in quotes there.

The same changes should also apply to the footnote, i.e. it should read "Springfield Shopper 2020" and "Brookman 2020".

Unfortunately, I can't find out where to modify the label. How can I achieve this?

I absolutely need the "in: " inside the bibliography, so I have to specify the `journal` field. If i set both the `journal` and `editor` fields to the newspaper name, the label looks OK, but then the newspaper name appears twice inside the bibliography (as journal and editor), which is pretty redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex`'s standard `authoryear` and `authortitle` style use the replacement `label` field if the `author`/`editor`/`translator` field is empty.

For some reason `arthistory-bonn` drops the date if `label` is used, so if you want to get that back, a few small changes are required.

For only the year instead of the full date we use `\printlabeldateextra` instead of the bibmacro `date+extradate`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,italian,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  style=arthistory-bonn,
  labeldate=year,
  autocite=footnote,
  language=auto,
  backref=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:normal}{%
 \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
 \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
   {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
   {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
     {\usebibmacro{cite:various}}%
     {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:various}{%
  \ifentrytype{catalog}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:catalog}}%
    {\ifentrytype{exhibcatalog}%
      {\usebibmacro{cite:exhibcatalog}}%
      {\ifentrytype{reference}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:reference}}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
           {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
         \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{News1,
    journal  = {Springfield Shopper},
    label    = {Springfield Shopper},
    title    = {The revolutionary monorail},
    year     = {2020},
    date     = {2020-12-23},
    url      = {http://example.com},
    urldate  = {2021-12-12}
}
@article{News2,
    journal  = {Springfield Shopper},
    title    = {About tire fires},
    year     = {2020},
    date     = {2020-12-23},
    url      = {http://example.com},
    urldate  = {2021-12-12},
    author   = {Kent Brookman},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
It's science if you quote things\autocite{News1,News2}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Springfield Shopper 2020]

Comment: Thanks! There is one issue: If multiple entries have the same `label` and `year`, they get identical names (i.e. 2× "Springfield Shopper 2020" instead of "Springfield Shopper 2020a" and "Springfield Shopper 2020b"). It works with sources that do have an author. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @Erlkoenig Good question. I don't think it is easy with the current version of `biblatex`, but with the current dev version (3.19dev) it is possible with `\DeclareExtradateContext` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1064).

Comment: Thanks, great! I managed to get it to work using the development version. Would you like to add it to the answer so I can accept it?